# How to assign custom colors to a map in Flutter without type mismatch errors?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, material-design, type-mismatch

I'm developing a Flutter application in Android Studio and facing a challenge with customizing color assignments. My goal is to assign specific `colors` to different statuses in my app. For some statuses, using predefined Colors works fine, such as `Colors.grey` for `PomodoroStatus.runningPomodoro`. However, when I attempt to assign custom colors, I encounter type mismatch errors stating "The element type 'Color' can't be assigned to the map value type 'MaterialColor'".

Here's a bit of context: I'm implementing a feature that changes the UI color based on the current status of a Pomodoro timer. The timer has several statuses, like running, paused, and types of breaks. I've created a map to associate each status with a corresponding color.

**Code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../model/pomodoro_status.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

const pomodoroTotalTime = 240 * 60;
const shortBreakTime = 20 * 60;
const lonBreakTime = 60 * 60;
const pomodoroPerSet = 4;

const Map<PomodoroStatus, String> statusDescription = {
  PomodoroStatus.runningPomodoro: 'Pomodoro is running, try to be focused',
  // Other status descriptions...
};

const Map<PomodoroStatus, MaterialColor> statusColor = {
  PomodoroStatus.runningPomodoro: Colors.grey, // Works fine
  // Custom color assignments below lead to errors
  PomodoroStatus.pausedPomodoro: const Color(0xFFC2C2C2),
  // Other status colors...
};
```

I've already tried consulting the Flutter documentation and searching for similar issues here, but couldn't find a scenario that matches mine exactly. Most solutions I found were related to using `Colors` directly, not custom `Color` values.

**Questions:**

1. How can I correctly assign custom `Color` values to my map without encountering type mismatch errors?
2. Is there a specific way to cast or convert `Color` objects to `MaterialColor` to fit the map's expected value type?

Any guidance or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `statusColor` map has `MaterialColor` as a value, so it will only accept colors within the `Colors` class.

Comment: How can I change to customize colors, what should I write to do so?

Comment: Just change the `MaterialColor` value of your map to just `Color`